# Hibernate throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to test Hibernate 4.2.1.Final with JPA using IntelliJ 12.1.3 and I am getting the following error.

Everything seems to be setup OK (I let IntelliJ generate the mappings), and as I have zero experience with Hibernate and JPA I am at a loss as to why this is occurring.

**Why am I getting an NPE on `EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Heroku-production");`?**

main class:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Heroku-production");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        List<CountryCodesEntity> result = entityManager.createQuery( "from CountryCodesEntity", CountryCodesEntity.class ).getResultList();
        for ( CountryCodesEntity countryCodesEntity : result ) {
            System.out.println( "Code (" + countryCodesEntity.getCode() + ") : " + countryCodesEntity.getNsenum() );
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

Error:

```
May 16, 2013 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
May 16, 2013 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.1.Final}
May 16, 2013 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 16, 2013 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/***/heroku/CountryCodesEntity.xml
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/***/heroku/StateCodesEntity.xml
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [postgres://*********:***********@ec2-***-**-**-*****.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6232/******]
May 16, 2013 3:02:54 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=********, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2293)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1758)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:913)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:898)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="Heroku-production">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>com/***/heroku/CountryCodesEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>com/***/heroku/StateCodesEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="postgres://****:****@ec2-***-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6232/*****"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="****"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That message indicates to me that its having trouble connecting to the db. Double check your connection string, and make sure your driver is on the classpath. I also think you need to have 'jdbc' as part of your connection string unless that's changed recently.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgres://****:****@ec2-***-**-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6232/*****"/>
```

Edit: I just eyeballed the source of previous version of this library, and if line 214 is the same b/t those two versions your connection is definitely null (i.e. not happening).

Here is line 214 of `DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl` in a version i have handy: (4.2.0.CR2)

```
214     if ( conn.getAutoCommit() != autocommit ) {
215         conn.setAutoCommit(autocommit);
216     }
```

Here are the preceding lines:

```
198     Connection conn;
199     if ( driver != null ) {
200         // If a Driver is available, completely circumvent
201         // DriverManager#getConnection.  It attempts to double check
202         // ClassLoaders before using a Driver.  This does not work well in
203         // OSGi environments without wonky workarounds.
204         conn = driver.connect( url, connectionProps );
205     }
206     else {
207         // If no Driver, fall back on the original method.
208         conn = DriverManager.getConnection( url, connectionProps );
209     }
210     
211     if ( isolation != null ) {
212         conn.setTransactionIsolation( isolation.intValue() );
213     }
214     if ( conn.getAutoCommit() != autocommit ) {
215         conn.setAutoCommit(autocommit);
216     }
```

Comment: I added jdbc to the connection string (was an omission on my part) but no luck. I'll take a look at the source.

Comment: Source is the same between the two. I'm going to alter the connection string and see where that leads me

Comment: No, that database is running with plain JDBC with no issues, same with using psql and PgAdmin III

Comment: Ok, so the connection string is the issue. Now I'm getting `The reference to entity "SSL" must end with the ';' delimiter.` as I require SSL to connect to the db.

Comment: try &amp;ssl=true&amp; @ the end of that connection string, though escaping the ampersands may not be necessary

Comment: I ended up needing to specify the username and password in the connection string via the `?username=blah&amp;password=blah` format with the addition of `&amp;ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`. Thanks for help.